# Running spring boot on server

Tags: java, web-services, spring-boot, server, debian

I have finally finished writing a very "simplistic" hello world project.
When I run it from my IDE, it works just fine.
When I run the jar on Windows 10 and I go to localhost (I am running on port 80) then I see the webpage and everything works just fine.
Once I drop that same jar on my debian server that has same mysql and java installed (and nothing else installed or configured) as my windows machine, and I try to navigate to the ip address I get

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun Feb 26 02:54:40 UTC 2017
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
Not Found
```

This tells me that the spring boot is running (because the second I shut it off I can't access the same page anymore), however I can not seem to navigate to any of the pages that I could on my windows machine.

I have absolutely no idea what I am doing wrong here.

EDIT:

Thanks to Oleksandr Shpota I am seeing why things do not work. My jar doesn't contain my freemarker files.

My build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'jetty'
apply plugin: 'war'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:1.5.1.RELEASE") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-webmvc', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context-support', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm', version: '4.3.6.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0'
    compile group: 'org.freemarker', name: 'freemarker', version: '2.3.23'
    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java', version: '6.0.5'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.1.4.Final'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.5.1'
    compile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test', version: '1.5.1.RELEASE'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '2.2'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

jar {
    from {
        (configurations.runtime).collect {
            it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it)
        }
    }
    baseName = 'carefree-cooking'
    version = '0.1.0'
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': 'carefree.cooking.Application'
    }
}

springBoot {
    executable = true
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

My Beans for configuring FreeMarker

```
@Bean(name = "freemarkerConfig")
public FreeMarkerConfigurer freemarkerConfig()
{
    FreeMarkerConfigurer configurer = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();
    configurer.setTemplateLoaderPath("/");
    return configurer;
}

@Bean(name = "viewResolver")
public FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver()
{
    FreeMarkerViewResolver viewResolver = new FreeMarkerViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/template/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".ftl");
    return viewResolver;
}
```

My index controller

```
@RequestMapping()
public String index(ModelMap model)
{
    log.info("======= We are in index controller going to load page");
    return "page";
}
```

And the `page.ftl` is in `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\template\page.ftl`

So the problem here is that when I build my jar, page.ftl is not included and neither is any of the webapp directory.

Comment: Can you post your console logs that you see in your IDE or terminal?

Comment: So you are building a jar and expect it to behave exactly as a `war`? Also Spring Boot already has free marker support out-of-the-box and you don't have to configure anything for it (and it works for both `jar` and `war` layout). I would also suggest to cleanup your build file as you already have `spring-boot-starter-web` but again declared a version of spring (to remove version conflicts). You can also remove the versions for most of the dependencies as the Spring Boot plugin will take care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your templates are in the wrong directory. You are creating a `jar` file which isn't a `war` file. However you have put the files in the location as it was a `war` file.

Also Spring Boot has Freemarker support out of the box so I would suggest you to use that, instead of manually configuring it yourself. So to fix.

1. Remove your Freemarker configuration
2. Move templates to `src/main/resources/templates`

Then restart your application.

As a bonus I suggest to cleanup your `build.gradle`. Remove the explicit versions for the starters and remove some additional dependencies because they are already included through the starters. You don't need the `jetty` and `war` plugins that is covered by Spring Boot.

And your jar plugin is breaking the default Spring Boot functionality, Spring Boot plugin takes care of that already.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web") {
        exclude module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
    }
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-jetty''
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-freemarker'

    compile group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-orm'

    compile group: 'mysql', name: 'mysql-connector-java'
    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core'
    compile group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.5.1'
    compileTest group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-test'
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '3.3'
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:1.5.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

springBoot {
    executable = true
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8
```

Comment: Thanks, I moved my `page.ftl` to `src/main/resources/templates`, it works when I run from IDE. The reason why I even made jar function is because when I run gradle clean jar, the jar generated is not a fat jar and thus does not contain spring boot jars and also it always says no main manifest attribute. And I have tried to modify my gradle and also removed everything but the jar function. Still doesn't work :( When I run it from my IDE it works however